# With LiveData observeForever what happen to the observer when the MainActivity is closed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-livedata, androidx, android-lifecycle

I have a service where I declare this liveData

```
public static final MutableLiveData<String> newMessageDispatcher = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

Inside the main activity I cannot do `newMessageDispatcher.observe(myActivity, newMessageObserver)` because my activity do not extends `AppCompatActivity` so it's not a `LifecycleOwner`.

Now If I do `newMessageDispatcher.observeForever(newMessageObserver)`, what will happen when the user will **close the app** (by swiping up in the recent apps window), so closing the main activity without calling `newMessageDispatcher.removeObserve(newMessageObserver)`? Does the observer will be successfully removed or do I absolutely need to call `newMessageDispatcher.removeObserve(newMessageObserver)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because my activity do not extends AppCompatActivity so it's not a LifecycleOwner.

You need to extend `ComponentActivity` to get `LifecycleOwner`. Or, you could implement `LifecycleOwner` logic yourself, if you wanted.

> what will happen when the user will close the app (by swiping up in the recent apps window), so closing the main activity without calling newMessageDispatcher.removeObserve(newMessageObserver)?

The precise behavior of that, or even if that behavior exists, will vary across the tens of thousands of Android device models.

> Does the observer will be successfully removed

You should not assume that it will.

> or do I absolutely need to call newMessageDispatcher.removeObserve(newMessageObserver)?

That would be a good idea. Do it in the counterpart lifecycle method to where you are calling `addObserver()` (e.g., if you call `addObserver()` in `onCreate()`, call `removeObserver()` in `onDestroy`()).

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare. but when the user close the app by swiping up in the recent apps window, the app will be suddenly closed and no ondestroy or anythink else will be called :( do you know how I can implement the LifecycleOwner myself ?

Comment: @zeus: "but when the user close the app by swiping up in the recent apps window, the app will be suddenly closed and no ondestroy or anythink else will be called" -- again, the behavior will vary by device model. If your process is terminated, then there is no need to unregister the observer, as the observer and the thing that it is observing is all gone. You could also call `addObserver()` in a different lifecycle method (e.g., `onPause()`) and `removeObserver()` in the counterpart (e.g,. `onResume()`).

Comment: "do you know how I can implement the LifecycleOwner myself ?" -- while it is in the context of a different problem, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/handstandsam/6ecff2f39da72c0b38c07aa80bbb5a2f) should give you some direction.